# Ignore alpha when rendering texture?

Tags: android, opengl-es

This *should* be simple but it's proving to be a real head-scratcher...

I have a texture with an alpha channel. On one render pass I want to render the texture but ignore the alpha channel. No matter what settings I use, pixels with alpha less than 1 are *not* drawn.

Surely any alpha testing/rejection/blending should be disabled by these commands?

```
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
```

I realise that I could work with two versions of the texture, one with alpha and one without. But surely there is a way to just ignore the alpha channel?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to use different source and destination blend modes for glBlendFunc than you're using now. If you, for example use GL_ONE for source and GL_ZERO for destination, then there will be no alpha pixels involved.

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFunc.xml

Comment: You would think so, but that produced the same results.

Comment: Well, that's really strange. This may be a stretch, but are you sure the 100% transparent pixels aren't the same color as the background you're drawing over? Keep in mind that current image-editing software makes it quite hard to control what happens with the R, G and B channels where the pixels are a 100% transparent. For this reason alone, I had to create an imaging tool-chain from Photoshop's PSD's to (in my case) PowerVR's PVRTC format. I had to jump through hoops to get full control of the RGB channels. Post code or a screenshot to give more info.